# Speech recognition syllable counter

Tags: msdn, praat

I'm wanting help in finding or creating an app or program that counts syllables with voice recognition. The application is for stuttering therapy; slowing the speech down,and joining/slurring words at slow speed (50 syllables per minute), and then slowly speeding up while practicing a modified way of speaking. Spending 2 days at 50 SPM (syllable per minute), and then the next few days at 80 spm, then next at 100 and so on. Until the stutterer is talking at 180 - 200 syllables per minute (normal speed) but with a  modified speech pattern (smooth speech) which significantly reduces the stutter. In the past I have used a hand held device, and manually counted the syllables, and told the speaker to slow down or speed up, depending on their syllable count.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [praat script to detect syllable nuclei](https://sites.google.com/site/speechrate/) that has been [published](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BRM.41.2.385) and validated. You may be able to use this script for your work, or it may be a good starting point for you to write your own.

You may also be interested in the Android app [SpeakRite](https://www.academia.edu/24513299/SpeakRite_Monitoring_speaking_rate_in_real_time_on_a_mobile_phone), which displays speaking rate in real time.